# Error about:blank#blocked

Tags: google-chrome, chrome

Al descargar un excel (generado en base a una tabla) me arroja el chrome este error.

He investigado, pero no se a que se puede deber.

¿Alguna ayuda para saber por que camino tirar?

Si que os puedo decir que si se seleccionan pocas líneas, funciona bien, pero si seleccionas un volumen más alto, da error.

Comment: cuál error? no adjuntaste algún archivo o lo que sale en el error.

Comment: Es el titulo del post, about:blank#blocked. El error es una pantalla de chrome blanca con eso en la url